Autofocus body input field when opening inline editor for answer posts
I'd like the body input field of an answer post's inline editor to be automatically focused when the inline editor gets opened.
At least in my personal workflow, when I open an answer post's inline editor, there's nothing else I want to do other than... edit it. And it's consistently an annoyance that I have to manually move focus into the body input field. For question posts, upon opening the inline editor, the title field is automatically focused (why not have similar behaviour for answer posts?).

I'm really expecting this request to be a duplicate... and yet am surprised that I can't find a dup-target from searching is:q [editor] focus here or on MSO... (am I the only person bothered by this?)

Sometimes things are just too trivial for someone to think about. :D (and BTW, you can just press TAB to focus, which is usually faster/easier than using a mouse)

@ShadowWizard I know I can use tab, but it's still really inconvenient. sometimes the tabbing "starts" from the editor action button bar, and sometimes, for reason I'm too lazy to figure out right now, it starts way away somewhere else.

Well to be fair, this is consistent with asking a new question: there's no auto focus, while it's expected to focus the title field. So it's already a total mess. lol
